# Embed different sound files in different pages of a pdf file

Tags: pdf, audio

I am looking for softwares on Mac and Windows (separate softwares are fine) which meet the following requirements:

1. Different sound files can be embedded into each page of a PDF file;
2. If you turn a page, the soud file in that page starts. As long as you stay in that page, no more sound. Then, if you turn a page, a new sound file starts......

This kind of software would be useful for remote teaching and other similar purposes.

I appreciate your recommendations.